# Samsung Smart TV remote control

Tags: websocket, reverse-engineering, samsung-smart-tv, remote-control

Where I can find samsung smart tv remote control protocol specification?
I've captured traffic of samsung smart view app with wireshark.
Communication is done using websockets but i don't know how GeneratorServerHello and ServerAckMsg is generated.

Comment: You can try browsing through the [SamsungIPRemote](https://github.com/Bntdumas/SamsungIPRemote) repo, check out how they are decoding the messages. Also, [this](http://sc0ty.pl/2012/02/samsung-tv-network-remote-control-protocol/) site has further information about the protocol.

Comment: This is the old protocol, my tv is using a new one (on port 8000 with websockets)